# create() function doesn't work and does not output an error (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, crud

i want insert data to database, but when i run function doesn't work and does not output an error, data not insert into database but is not show an error? why i should i do ?

```
public function index(){
    $data_subgroup = \App\Subgroup::all();
    $data_category = \App\Module::all();
    return view('/dashboard/subgroup', ['data_subgroup' => $data_subgroup,
                                        'data_category' => $data_category,                                        
    ]);
}

public function create(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'subgroup_logo' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        'subgroup_name' => 'required',
        'module_id'     => 'required'
    ]);

    $subgroup_logo = $request->file('subgroup_logo');
        $filename ='subgroups/'  . time() . '.' . $subgroup_logo->getClientOriginalExtension(); //Memecah Filename
        Image::make($subgroup_logo)->resize(200, 200)->save( public_path('/uploads/' . $filename)); //Resize dan Save Avatar ke Database

    Subgroup::create([
        'subgroup_logo' => $filename,
        'subgroup_name' => $request->subgroup_name,
        'module_id'   => $request->module_id
    ]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This my Route  code:

```
    Route::get('/dashboard/subgroup', 'Dashboard\SubgroupController@index');
Route::post('/dashboard/subgroup/create', 'Dashboard\SubgroupController@create');
```

This my Model code:

```
class Subgroup extends Model{
protected $table = 'subgroup';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $primaryKey = 'subgroup_id';

protected $fillable = ['subgroup_id', 'subgroup_name', 'subgroup_logo', 'module_id'];

public function module(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Module' , 'module_id');
}
```

}

UPDATE :
i think error is from insert data from select option,

i change :

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'subgroup_logo' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    'subgroup_name' => 'required',
    'module_id'     => 'required'
]);
```

to :

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'subgroup_logo' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        'subgroup_name' => 'required',
        'module_id'     => 'integer|required'
    ]);
```

i have select option views :

```
<label for="category">Select Category</label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        @foreach($data_category as $category)
                        <option id="module_id" name="module_id" value="{{$category->module_id}}">
                            {{$category->module_name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
```

I have error :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'module_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `subgroup`
>   (`subgroup_logo`, `subgroup_name`, `module_id`) values
>   (subgroups/1570166504.png, UNSIKA, ?))

Comment: Show Subgroup eloquent model class.

Comment: I think your form is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @ZainFarooq i have enctype

Comment: Have you set action properly inside form?

Comment: @ZainFarooq my  action="/dashboard/subgroup/create"

Comment: Try this. First name the route `Route::post('/dashboard/subgroup/create', 'Dashboard\SubgroupController@create')->name(create);` then in form `action="{{ route('create') }}"`

Comment: @Zeshan i have edit my post

Comment: @ZainFarooq i think error not from route or action form, because my redirect on function create work

Comment: I think the problem is in your validation rule. Try remove this `'subgroup_logo' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',`

Comment: please pass csrf token in your form.

Comment: And then submit the form

Comment: @PHP i have set csrf token

Comment: @ZainFarooq not work, result still same

Comment: Debug your code step by step. We can't figure out the problem exactly on your side.

Comment: please put your form code..

Comment: @ZainFarooq please see my update post

Comment: @PHP please see my update post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set name attribute to your select input. You have set it in `option` tag which is wrong

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="module_id">
                        @foreach($data_category as $category)
                        <option id="module_id" name="module_id" value="{{$category->module_id}}">
                            {{$category->module_name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//set name and id attribute to your select input then check it.it's should 
//  be works properly.

  <label for="category">Select Category</label>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="module_id" id="module_id">
      @foreach($data_category as $category)
          <option value="{{$category->module_id}}">
              {{$category->module_name}}</option>
      @endforeach      
  </select>
```